# Disabling Auto-generated comments in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments, enterprise

I would like to disable auto generated comments of Visual Studio every time I create new project. Sample template of visual studio can be seen below. I don't want any of these comments. Thanks for any help.

```
 `   
 // ex6_page174.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program 
 execution begins and ends there.
 //

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > 
Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > 
Project and select the .sln file

`
```

Comment: Weird. Press F5 executes the code. What/where do you see auto generated comments? Haven't run across this and I also use(d) the VS2017 Enterprise edition. But I mostly code from scratch.

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding

Comment: I doubt if "project template" may help.  Not sure.

Comment: What do you mean? I create project and this unneccesary comments appear like "//Tips for getting started" and I don't want them. That's it.

Comment: Just create empty projects and add and name whatever files you want. These template, starter projects, are for newbies. Who wants to start a project with Hello World unless they are totally new to VS or coding. I also don't usually use pch files so starting a project that way requires cleaning up the structure and dropping the pch option.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way to change default Windows Console Application format so it is better starting form scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

For better or for worse, [this is by design](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/488725/how-to-get-rid-of-tips-for-getting-started.html).